# Is the proxy pattern an anti pattern? (DIP violation?)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, anti-patterns

Proxy object dependence on Concrete class. But DIP(in OOP principle) said below.

A. HIGH LEVEL MODULES SHOULD NOT DEPEND UPON LOW LEVEL MODULES. BOTH SHOULD DEPEND UPON ABSTRACTIONS.

B. ABSTRACTIONS SHOULD NOT DEPEND UPON DETAILS. DETAILS SHOULD DEPEND UPON ABSTRACTIONS.

Is the proxy object an anti pattern because of it depending upon 'detail'?

Comment: 1. principles are just that: principles. 2. Why would the proxy pattern consist in depending upon details? It doesn't.

Comment: @JBNizet 2. because proxy object has composition or dependency relation on real instance. Can't I say proxy pattern depending upon detail? I think depending on concrete class is depending upon detail

Comment: It has a dependency on a real instance of an abstraction. Take a BufferedInputStream for example: it's a buffering proxy around any other InputStream, and it doesn't care or even know about the concrete type of the proxied InputStream.

Comment: @JBNizet But UML class and sequence diagram in wiki page(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) said proxy has dependency on  "RealSubject" class not "Subject". Can you explain that dependency on RealSubject class is not depend upon detail?

Comment: @JBNizet Or... you saying "RealSubject" is abstraction of another class?

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that the end goal of the proxy is to... proxy to real instances of an abstraction. Because in the end, something real has to do the job. That doesn't necessarily mean that the proxy has a hard dependency on the real concrete implementation of the Subject abstraction. How the proxy gets an instance of the proxied object is an orthogonal matter: it can create it by itself, or someone can inject it. It doesn't matter for the proxy pattern.

Comment: @JBNizet thx. I understand. Can you rewrite your opinion as answer? I want choice your answer.